# matlab - matrix to vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have (n x n) matrix in Matlab. For example(n=3):

```
A=[1,2,3; 4,5,6; 1,9,9]
```

I want save this matrix to vector (or array) B, but rows should be first. 
Output:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,9,9]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways:

1. Use `reshape`:

   ```
   B = reshape(A.',1,[]);
   ```
2. Use `vec2mat` from the Communications Toolbox:

   ```
   B = vec2mat(A,numel(A));
   ```
3. Transpose `A` and then use linear indexing:

   ```
   A = A.';
   B = A(:).'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Besides @LuisMendo's answer using `reshape` or `vec2mat`, you can also use

**Method 1:**

```
B = A';
C = B(:)' % final result
```

**Method 2:**

```
C = subsref(A.', substruct('()', {':'})).'  % final result
```

Comment: This doesn't give the desired order, does it?